# How to use C# .NET Core to save and access documents from OpenSearch?

Tags: c#, .net-core, opensearch, amazon-opensearch

I am trying to save and fetch data from OpenSearch using C# .NET Core.

## What I did:

1. On my local system I have setup OpenSearch by following: [Using OpenSearch with Docker Compose](https://opensearch.org/downloads.html).
2. Upon using the command: `docker-compose up -d`, containers are successfully running and I am able to login to OpenSearch Dashboard via my browser.
3. Created a fresh .NET Core project and added `OpenSearch.Client (1.6.0)` package to it.
4. Here is the code snippet used to save an object of type `Student` to an already created (*I have also tried by not created the index*) index: `students`

```
public class OpenSearchController : ControllerBase
{
  private const String _admin = "admin";
  private const String _indexStudents = "pmg-students";

  //---------------tried these multiple URLs but none of them seems to work---------------
  private const String _localhostUrl = "https://localhost:9200/";
  private const String _node1Address = "https://opensearch-node1:9200";
  private const String _node2Address = "https://opensearch-node2:9200";
  private const String _myServer = "http://myserver:9200";

  public IActionResult Add(Student student)
  {
    //----- When using this config, I get error: 'OriginalException: OpenSearch.Net.OpenSearchClientException: Request failed to execute. Call: Status code 404 from: PUT /students/_doc/1'
    var node = new Uri(_localhostUrl);
    var config = new ConnectionSettings(node)
       .ServerCertificateValidationCallback((o, certificate, chain, errors) => true)
       .ServerCertificateValidationCallback(CertificateValidations.AllowAll)
       .BasicAuthentication(_admin, _admin)
       .DisableDirectStreaming();

    //----- When using this config, I get error: 'The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure: RemoteCertificateNameMismatch'
    var node = new Uri(_localhostUrl);
    var config = new ConnectionSettings(node).DefaultIndex(_indexStudents);

    //----- updated as per Ralf's comment, error: 'OriginalException: OpenSearch.Net.OpenSearchClientException: Request failed to execute. Call: Status code 404 from: PUT /students/_doc/1'
    var node = new Uri(_localhostUrl);
    var config = new ConnectionSettings(node)
       .ServerCertificateValidationCallback((o, certificate, chain, errors) => true)
       .ServerCertificateValidationCallback(CertificateValidations.AllowAll)
       .DefaultIndex(_indexStudents);

    var client = new OpenSearchClient(config);   
    var response = client.Index(student, i => i.Index(_indexStudents));
    return new JsonResult(response);
  }
}
```

5. Tried [disabling certificates](https://github.com/opensearch-project/opensearch-build/blob/main/docker/release/README.md#scenario-3-no-demo-certsconfigs--enable-security-on-both-opensearch-and-opensearch-dashboards-cluster-exit-with-errors-due-to-demo-install-script-is-not-run-therefore-no-certsconfigs-are-available-for-security-plugin-useful-if-you-want-to-setup-your-own-certsconfigs) as well.
6. Browsed through the [samples](https://github.com/opensearch-project/opensearch-net/blob/main/samples/Samples/Utils/OpenSearchClientOptions.cs) provided by the [opensearch-project](https://github.com/opensearch-project/opensearch-net) on GitHub.
7. And of course, went through the [official OpenSearch documentation](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/clients/OSC-dot-net/#connecting-to-opensearch).

## What I am I missing?

I don't know, yet.

## What I want to do:

To save and fetch documents from OpenSearch (running on my local system) for a POC, without getting involved with certificates and their errors??

Comment: You no longer set the ServerCertificateValidationCallback in the second call so you get default behavior here and that should be to disallow insecure certs.

Comment: @Ralf I tried what you suggested and updated my question as well. But it still gives the error.

Answer (score 0):

After investing much time I was able to figure out how to hit the OpenSearch URL on Windows 11 via C# .NET. And it has nothing to do with C# .NET.

All this time I was trying to access the `https://localhost:9200` on Windows 11, while OpenSearch was running on the `9200` port of a different IP address.

This is how I did it:

1. First I [installed Docker Engine and Docker Compose on WSL 2 in Windows 11](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/install-docker-in-wsl-2-without-docker-desktop)
2. Then [download](https://opensearch.org/downloads.html) and run OpenSearch
3. On your WSL 2 shell, execute: `ip addr`, the IP address mentioned in `eth0` is where the OpenSearch is running.
4. To verify, execute: `curl https://ip.address.from.eth0:9200 -ku 'admin:admin'` on WSL 2 shell.
5. And voilà, your will get a response that looks like this (if you have correctly installed docker, docker compose and OpenSearch):

```
{
  "name" : "a937e018cee5",
  "cluster_name" : "docker-cluster",
  "cluster_uuid" : "GLAjAG6bTeWErFUy_d-CLw",
  "version" : {
    "distribution" : "opensearch",
    "number" : <version>,
    "build_type" : <build-type>,
    "build_hash" : <build-hash>,
    "build_date" : <build-date>,
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : <lucene-version>,
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "7.10.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "7.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "The OpenSearch Project: https://opensearch.org/"
}
```

This means that OpenSearch is running on the specified IP address, and now you can use it in your .NET application and it will work.